# Debug android app termination

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am currently implementing my first Android app. Debugging and developing goes usually fine but sometimes I have problem when doing some changes in my code and then starting the app again from Eclipse environment (to virtual device).

As far as I understand it, new start terminates the currently running version of my app in the emulator, that's fine - but is this some correct termination? Is some event raised in my app which I should handle?

Why am I asking? My problem is that for most of the Activities being currently active in the emulator my app terminates (it's gone) correctly and new version starts fine. But for about 2 of my Activities when they are active and I "restart" my app from Eclipse I can see for a few seconds message box "Unfortunately APP has stopped" and that gives me an idea that these Activities have probably to do something in their destructor, uninitialize something or whatever because termination causes some kind of crash. How to detect this, how to debug this? When I start the app again, the old version debugger is disconnected so it's not helping. All I can see is logcat exception call stack info but it's not helping me too much:

```
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:379)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
01-19 11:19:16.352: E/AndroidRuntime(1424):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: its getting null pointer exception. check out you are missing some values ..

Comment: Thanks. Well I know it is NullPointerException but how can I debug it when debugger is disconnected when I start new instance of my app? I don't know what method is called when app terminates and so where should I change something. When I just run and close it normally it works fine. I suppose only some destructors are called when app is forced to close? I don't use OnDestroy so there is not a problem of using some null value...

Comment: so if you run normally then its running is it ?

Comment: When I just run it in emulator (does not matter if just run or in debug mode) and close it, everything is ok. Problem is only when about 2 of my activities are currently active and I start the app again from Eclipse... the old instance in emulator is forced to close and causes this problem (when different activities are active, it stopps ok). Then new instance of the app is started ok.

Comment: When I close app in the emulator in the list of running apps then it terminates ok. NullPointerException occures only when starting app once again from the Eclipse. Maybe it is some nonstandard way of closing the previous version of app but what confuses me is that it occures only when some of my activities are currently active, not for others, so it is some bug on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugger problem, app terminated in bad way, not real issue.